# Unity 2D Character Vibrates When Touching Wall

Tags: c#, 2d

Like the title says when i walk into a wall i start to vibrate. It doesn't affect gameplay just graphics i believe. The game is a 2D platformer using rigidbody 2D. I am new to game dev so what you fixed could you please tell me how you fix it. Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 1;
    public float JumpForce = 1;

    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;

    private float coyoteTime = 0.2f;
    private float coyoteTimeCounter;

    private float jumpBufferTime = 0.05f;
    private float jumpBufferCounter;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;

    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded())
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpBufferCounter = jumpBufferTime;
        }
        else
        {
            jumpBufferCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;

        if (coyoteTimeCounter > 0f && jumpBufferCounter > 0f)
        {
            _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody.velocity.x, JumpForce);

            jumpBufferCounter = 0f;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && _rigidbody.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(_rigidbody.velocity.x, _rigidbody.velocity.y * 0.5f);

            coyoteTimeCounter = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if the code is sort of sloppy. I am using multiple tutorials to make the movement perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! I have had this problem before.

The reason the vibration is happening, is because you are adding a force manually through `rigidbody.velocity`. The better (And more efficient) way to do it is through `rigidbody.AddForce()`. [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) should allow for the rigidbody to calculate physics much smoother.

The only issue that may arise is if you plan for the player to have a constant speed. If you AddForce(1000) with no other arguments, the character will start accelerating, instead of moving at a constant speed.

If you need the player to move at a constant speed, you can append a [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) to! I am not sure what one you would use, but that my idea. One example would be `rigidbody.AddForce(1000, ForceMode.VelocityChange)`,

Comment: thank you i wanted him to accelerate anyways. although idk how to add the AddForce() because it gives error 1501 no overload for method 'AddForce'

Comment: Could you please answer back i can't continue without it